# Android: No SIM. How show custom message?

Tags: android

My phone layout.xml

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/textViewPhoneValue"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:autoLink="phone"
   android:textColorLink="@color/color_blue" />
```

As result my phone number is show as link. And when click it's call.
Nice.

But if smartphone has no SIM card then I get error: **Mobile network not available.**

But I need to show my custom error message BEFORE try to calling. Something like: "**No sim card**"

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the getSimOperator() method to see the info. If the info is null then the device doesn't carry a SIM Card.

```
public String getSimInfo(){
    TelephonyManager tmn= (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String name = tmn.getSimOperator();
    return name; 
}
```

Comment: First I need handle link click. How I can do this?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this. You can add an on click listener to the TextView and inside you call the number using Intent.ACTION_CALL. Or you can set the text data inside the textview using Html.fromHtml() and put a href link with tel: extension. And you can easily call the above method to see if the call can be placed.